# jQuery UI: Can an object be selectable and draggable simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have objects that I want to be both draggable and selectable. Is this possible?

```
var course_li = $(sprintf('<li class="course%s">%s</li>', already_scheduled_class, course["fields"]["name"]));

// ...

course_li.draggable(DRAGGABLE_COURSE_SETTINGS);

// ...

if (in_course) {
      course_li.draggable('disable');
}   

// ...

$(".course").selectable(); // fail
```

Everything is good until it gets to that last line. That appears to cause an exception in jQuery:

```
elem.ownerDocument is null
```

This occurs on line 4691 of jQuery.js (1.4.2):

```
var defaultView = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView;
```

Am I doing something wrong here, or is selectable and draggable just incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get elements to be both `selectable` and `draggable`, but it was easy enough to have a parent container div that's draggable, with a child unordered list (`<ul>`) that's selectable.  Here's my code (tested):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .sel
        {
            padding: 20px;
            border: solid 1px #000;
            list-style-type: none;
            background-color: #c0c0c0;
            width: 90%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        .sel .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
        .sel .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: #fff; }
        .sel li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }

        .drag
        {
            margin: 10px;
            border: solid 1px #f00;
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(".sel").selectable();
            $(".drag").draggable();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="drag">
        Drag me
        <ul class="sel">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does a `selectable` element have to be a list where the list elements are what gets selected?

Comment: No, you could have a `<table class="sel">...</table>` and do `$(".sel").selectable({ filter: "tr" });`, and that would make your individual <tr>'s selectable.

Comment: It appears you can use any valid jquery selector for the `filter` property when providing your options for `selectable()`.  So you could use spans, divs, whatever.  Just match the elements with `filter`.